# JAVA SAX parsing into hash map and printing out

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I don't know if I'm parsing in correctly or if i'm printing out incorrectly from a the hashmap?  I think i must be parsing incorrectly because when I check the values I get null.

main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    { 
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser(); 
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 
        xr.setContentHandler(new DrugbankHandler()); 
        xr.parse("c:\\drugbank.xml");
      System.out.println(DrugbankHandler.lookupCache);
       // DrugbankHandler.printMap();
```

contenthandler.java

```
public class DrugbankHandler implements ContentHandler {

    boolean drugFound;
    boolean nameFound;
    boolean drugInteraction;
    boolean drugID;
    boolean packager;
    boolean calculatedProperties;
    boolean kindFound;
    boolean inChiKeyValueFound;
    boolean nextValueIsInChiKey;
    boolean isSmallMolecule;
    boolean property;
    boolean previousTagWasDrugID;

    DrugModel tempDrugModel;

    /**
     * stores key (drugbank-id), value (drug model) pairs
     */
    public final static  HashMap<String, DrugModel> lookupCache = new HashMap<String, DrugModel>(
            7000);

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        //System.out.print(atts); 
        if (tempDrugModel != null && tempDrugModel.drugbankID.equals("DB00002")) {
            System.out.println(localName);
            if (localName.equals("value")) {
                System.out.print("");
            }
        }

        if (localName.equals("drug-interaction")) {
            drugInteraction = true;
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("drug") && !drugInteraction
                && atts.getLength() > 0) {
            if (atts.getValue("type").equals("biotech"))
                return;
            drugFound = true;
            tempDrugModel = new DrugModel();
            String type = atts.getValue("type");
            if (type.startsWith("small"))
                isSmallMolecule = true;
            else
                isSmallMolecule = false;

            tempDrugModel.isSmallMolecule = isSmallMolecule;

            return;
        }
        if (localName.equals("drugbank-id")) {
            drugID = true;
            return;
        }
        if (previousTagWasDrugID && localName.equals("name")) {
            nameFound = true;
            return;
        }
        // if drug is a small molecule read its InChIKey value
        /**
         * <calculated-properties> <property> <kind>InChI</kind>
         * <value>InChIKey=hurensohn</value> <source>JChem</source> </property>
         * .... </calculated-properties>
         */
        if (isSmallMolecule) {
            if (calculatedProperties && localName.equals("property")) {
                property = true;
                return;
            }
            if (property && localName.equals("kind")) {
                kindFound = true;
                return;
            }
            if (localName.equals("calculated-properties")) {
                calculatedProperties = true;
                return;
            }
            if (nextValueIsInChiKey && localName.equals("value")) {
                inChiKeyValueFound = true;
                nextValueIsInChiKey = false;
                return;
            }
        } else {
            // TODO which id or feature to lookup peptides in chembl?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if (drugFound && !drugInteraction && localName.equals("drug")) {
            drugFound = false;
            lookupCache.put(tempDrugModel.drugbankID, tempDrugModel);
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("drugbank-id")) {
            previousTagWasDrugID = true;
        }
        if (localName.equals("drug-interaction")) {
            drugInteraction = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if (!drugFound)
            return;

        if (nameFound) {
            tempDrugModel.name = new String(ch, start, length);
            previousTagWasDrugID = false;
            nameFound = false;
            return;
        }
        if (drugID) {
            tempDrugModel.drugbankID = new String(ch, start, length);
            drugID = false;
            return;
        }
        if (kindFound) {
            String kind = new String(ch, start, length);
            if (kind.equals("InChIKey")) {
                nextValueIsInChiKey = true;
            }
            kindFound = false;
            return;
        }
        if (inChiKeyValueFound) {
            // skip the "InChIKey=" prefix of length 9
            String k = new String(ch, start + 9, length - 9);
            tempDrugModel.InChiKey = k;
            inChiKeyValueFound = false;
            return;
        }
    }


    public static void printMap() {
        /*Iterator it = lookupCache.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
            String val = (String)entry.getValue();



            System.out.println(lookupCache);

        }*/
         System.out.println(lookupCache);
 } 
    // ignored methods following...

    @Override
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data)
            throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
            throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
    }
}
```

sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drugs xmlns="http://drugbank.ca" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaVersion="2.0" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd">
<drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13 07:24:05 -0600" updated="2013-05-12 21:37:25 -0600" version="4.0">
  <drugbank-id>DB00001</drugbank-id>
  <name>Lepirudin</name>
  <description>Lepirudin is identical to natural hirudin except for substitution of leucine for isoleucine at the N-terminal end of the molecule and the absence of a sulfate group on the tyrosine at position 63. It is produced via yeast cells.&#13;
</description>
  <cas-number>120993-53-5</cas-number>
  <general-references># Smythe MA, Stephens JL, Koerber JM, Mattson JC: A comparison of lepirudin and argatroban outcomes. Clin Appl Thromb Hemost. 2005 Oct;11(4):371-4. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16244762&#13;
# Tardy B, Lecompte T, Boelhen F, Tardy-Poncet B, Elalamy I, Morange P, Gruel Y, Wolf M, Francois D, Racadot E, Camarasa P, Blouch MT, Nguyen F, Doubine S, Dutrillaux F, Alhenc-Gelas M, Martin-Toutain I, Bauters A, Ffrench P, de Maistre E, Grunebaum L, Mouton C, Huisse MG, Gouault-Heilmann M, Lucke V: Predictive factors for thrombosis and major bleeding in an observational study in 181 patients with heparin-induced thrombocytopenia treated with lepirudin. Blood. 2006 Sep 1;108(5):1492-6. Epub 2006 May 11. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16690967&#13;
# Lubenow N, Eichler P, Lietz T, Greinacher A: Lepirudin in patients with heparin-induced thrombocytopenia - results of the third prospective study (HAT-3) and a combined analysis of HAT-1, HAT-2, and HAT-3. J Thromb Haemost. 2005 Nov;3(11):2428-36. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16241940&#13;
# Askari AT, Lincoff AM: Antithrombotic Drug Therapy in Cardiovascular Disease. 2009 Oct; pp. 440–. ISBN 9781603272346. "Google books":http://books.google.com/books?id=iadLoXoQkWEC&amp;pg=PA440. </general-references>
  <synthesis-reference/>
  <indication>For the treatment of heparin-induced thrombocytopenia</indication>
  <pharmacology>Lepirudin is used to break up clots and to reduce thrombocytopenia. It binds to thrombin and prevents thrombus or clot formation. It is a highly potent, selective, and essentially irreversible inhibitor of thrombin and clot-bond thrombin. Lepirudin requires no cofactor for its anticoagulant action. Lepirudin is a recombinant form of hirudin, an endogenous anticoagulant found in medicinal leeches.</pharmacology>
  <mechanism-of-action>Lepirudin forms a stable non-covalent complex with alpha-thrombin, thereby abolishing its ability to cleave fibrinogen and initiate the clotting cascade. The inhibition of thrombin prevents the blood clotting cascade. </mechanism-of-action>
  <toxicity>In case of overdose (eg, suggested by excessively high aPTT values) the risk of bleeding is increased.</toxicity>
  <biotransformation>Lepirudin is thought to be metabolized by release of amino acids via catabolic hydrolysis of the parent drug. However, con-clusive data are not available. About 48% of the administration dose is excreted in the urine which consists of unchanged drug (35%) and other fragments of the parent drug.</biotransformation>
  <absorption>Bioavailability is 100% following injection.</absorption>
  <half-life>Approximately 1.3 hours</half-life>
  <protein-binding/>
  <route-of-elimination>Lepirudin is thought to be metabolized by release of amino acids via catabolic hydrolysis of the parent drug. About 48% of the administration dose is excreted in the urine which consists of unchanged drug (35%) and other fragments of the parent drug.</route-of-elimination>
  <volume-of-distribution>* 12.2 L [Healthy young subjects (n = 18, age 18-60 years)]&#13;
* 18.7 L [Healthy elderly subjects (n = 10, age 65-80 years)]&#13;
* 18 L [Renally impaired patients (n = 16, creatinine clearance below 80 mL/min)]&#13;
* 32.1 L [HIT patients (n = 73)]</volume-of-distribution>
  <clearance>* 164 ml/min [Healthy 18-60 yrs]&#13;
* 139 ml/min [Healthy 65-80 yrs]&#13;
* 61 ml/min [renal impaired]&#13;
* 114 ml/min [HIT (Heparin-induced thrombocytopenia)]</clearance>
  <secondary-accession-numbers>
    <secondary-accession-number>BIOD00024</secondary-accession-number>
    <secondary-accession-number>BTD00024</secondary-accession-number>
  </secondary-accession-numbers>
  <groups>
    <group>approved</group>
  </groups>
  <taxonomy>
    <kingdom/>
    <substructures/>
  </taxonomy>
  <synonyms>
    <synonym>Hirudin variant-1</synonym>
  </synonyms>
  <salts/>
  <brands>
    <brand>Refludan</brand>
  </brands>
  <mixtures/>
  <packagers>
    <packager>
      <name>Bayer Healthcare</name>
      <url>http://www.bayerhealthcare.com</url>
    </packager>
    <packager>
      <name>Berlex Labs</name>
      <url>http://www.berlex.com</url>
    </packager>
  </packagers>
  <manufacturers>
    <manufacturer generic="false">Bayer healthcare pharmaceuticals inc</manufacturer>
  </manufacturers>
  <prices>
    <price>
      <description>Refludan 50 mg vial</description>
      <cost currency="USD">273.19</cost>
      <unit>vial</unit>
    </price>
  </prices>
  <categories>
    <category>Antithrombins</category>
    <category>Fibrinolytic Agents</category>
  </categories>
  <affected-organisms>
    <affected-organism>Humans and other mammals</affected-organism>
  </affected-organisms>
  <dosages>
    <dosage>
      <form>Powder, for solution</form>
      <route>Intravenous</route>
      <strength/>
    </dosage>
  </dosages>
  <atc-codes>
    <atc-code>B01AE02</atc-code>
    <category/>
  </atc-codes>
  <ahfs-codes>
    <ahfs-code>20:12.04.12</ahfs-code>
  </ahfs-codes>
  <patents>
    <patent>
      <number>5180668</number>
      <country>United States</country>
      <approved>1993-01-19</approved>
      <expires>2010-01-19</expires>
    </patent>
    <patent>
      <number>1339104</number>
      <country>Canada</country>
      <approved>1997-07-29</approved>
      <expires>2014-07-29</expires>
    </patent>
  </patents>
  <food-interactions/>
  <drug-interactions>
    <drug-interaction>
      <drug>DB01381</drug>
      <name>Ginkgo biloba</name>
      <description>Additive anticoagulant/antiplatelet effects may increase bleed risk. Concomitant therapy should be avoided.</description>
    </drug-interaction>
    <drug-interaction>
      <drug>DB00374</drug>
      <name>Treprostinil</name>
      <description>The prostacyclin analogue, Treprostinil, increases the risk of bleeding when combined with the anticoagulant, Lepirudin. Monitor for increased bleeding during concomitant thearpy. </description>
    </drug-interaction>
  </drug-interactions>
  <protein-sequences>
    <fasta>
      <fasta>#&lt;PolypeptideSequence:0x007f1d1efef190&gt;</fasta>
    </fasta>
  </protein-sequences>
  <experimental-properties>
    <property>
      <kind>Melting Point</kind>
      <value>65 °C</value>
      <source>Otto, A. &amp; Seckler, R. Eur. J. Biochem. 202:67-73 (1991)</source>
    </property>
    <property>
      <kind>Hydrophobicity</kind>
      <value>-0.777</value>
      <source/>
    </property>
    <property>
      <kind>Isoelectric Point</kind>
      <value>4.04</value>
      <source/>
    </property>
    <property>
      <kind>Molecular Weight</kind>
      <value>6963.4250</value>
      <source/>
    </property>
    <property>
      <kind>Molecular Formula</kind>
      <value>C287H440N80O110S6</value>
      <source/>
    </property>
  </experimental-properties>
  <external-identifiers>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>Drugs Product Database (DPD)</resource>
      <identifier>2240996</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>KEGG Drug</resource>
      <identifier>D06880</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>National Drug Code Directory</resource>
      <identifier>50419-150-57</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>PharmGKB</resource>
      <identifier>PA450195</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>UniProtKB</resource>
      <identifier>P01050</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>Wikipedia</resource>
      <identifier>Lepirudin</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
  </external-identifiers>
  <external-links>
    <external-link>
      <resource>RxList</resource>
      <url>http://www.rxlist.com/cgi/generic/lepirudin.htm</url>
    </external-link>
    <external-link>
      <resource>Drugs.com</resource>
      <url>http://www.drugs.com/cdi/lepirudin.html</url>
    </external-link>
  </external-links>
  <targets>
    <target>
      <id>BE0000048</id>
      <name>Prothrombin</name>
      <organism>Human</organism>
      <actions>
        <action>inhibitor</action>
      </actions>
      <references># Turpie AG: Anticoagulants in acute coronary syndromes. Am J Cardiol. 1999 Sep 2;84(5A):2M-6M. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10505536&#13;
# Warkentin TE: Venous thromboembolism in heparin-induced thrombocytopenia. Curr Opin Pulm Med. 2000 Jul;6(4):343-51. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10912644&#13;
# Eriksson BI: New therapeutic options in deep vein thrombosis prophylaxis. Semin Hematol. 2000 Jul;37(3 Suppl 5):7-9. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11055889&#13;
# Fabrizio MC: Use of ecarin clotting time (ECT) with lepirudin therapy in heparin-induced thrombocytopenia and cardiopulmonary bypass. J Extra Corpor Technol. 2001 May;33(2):117-25. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11467439&#13;
# Szaba FM, Smiley ST: Roles for thrombin and fibrin(ogen) in cytokine/chemokine production and macrophage adhesion in vivo. Blood. 2002 Feb 1;99(3):1053-9. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11807012&#13;
# Chen X, Ji ZL, Chen YZ: TTD: Therapeutic Target Database. Nucleic Acids Res. 2002 Jan 1;30(1):412-5. "Pubmed":http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11752352</references>
      <known-action>yes</known-action>
      <components>
        <polypeptide id="P00734">
          <name>Prothrombin</name>
          <general-function>Involved in blood clotting cascade</general-function>
          <specific-function>Thrombin, which cleaves bonds after Arg and Lys, converts fibrinogen to fibrin and activates factors V, VII, VIII, XIII, and, in complex with thrombomodulin, protein C</specific-function>
          <gene-name>F2</gene-name>
          <locus>11p11-q12</locus>
          <cellular-location>Secreted protein; extracellular space</cellular-location>
          <transmembrane-regions>None</transmembrane-regions>
          <theoretical-pi>5.7</theoretical-pi>
          <molecular-weight>70037.0</molecular-weight>
          <chromosome-location/>
          <external-identifiers>
            <external-identifier>
              <resource>HUGO Gene Nomenclature Committee (HGNC)</resource>
              <identifier>HGNC:3535</identifier>
            </external-identifier>
            <external-identifier>
              <resource>GenAtlas</resource>
              <identifier>F2</identifier>
            </external-identifier>
            <external-identifier>
              <resource>GeneCards</resource>
              <identifier>F2</identifier>
            </external-identifier>
            <external-identifier>
              <resource>GenBank Gene Database</resource>
              <identifier>M17262</identifier>
            </external-identifier>
            <external-identifier>
              <resource>GenBank Protein Database</resource>
              <identifier>339641</identifier>
            </external-identifier>
            <external-identifier>
              <resource>UniProtKB</resource>
              <identifier>P00734</identifier>
            </external-identifier>
          </external-identifiers>
          <synonyms>
            <synonym>Activated Factor II [IIa]</synonym>
            <synonym>Coagulation factor II</synonym>
            <synonym>EC 3.4.21.5</synonym>
            <synonym>Prothrombin precursor</synonym>
            <synonym>Thrombin</synonym>
          </synonyms>
          <amino-acid-sequence>
            <fasta>&gt;Prothrombin precursor
MAHVRGLQLPGCLALAALCSLVHSQHVFLAPQQARSLLQRVRRANTFLEEVRKGNLEREC
VEETCSYEEAFEALESSTATDVFWAKYTACETARTPRDKLAACLEGNCAEGLGTNYRGHV
NITRSGIECQLWRSRYPHKPEINSTTHPGADLQENFCRNPDSSTTGPWCYTTDPTVRRQE
CSIPVCGQDQVTVAMTPRSEGSSVNLSPPLEQCVPDRGQQYQGRLAVTTHGLPCLAWASA
QAKALSKHQDFNSAVQLVENFCRNPDGDEEGVWCYVAGKPGDFGYCDLNYCEEAVEEETG
DGLDEDSDRAIEGRTATSEYQTFFNPRTFGSGEADCGLRPLFEKKSLEDKTERELLESYI
DGRIVEGSDAEIGMSPWQVMLFRKSPQELLCGASLISDRWVLTAAHCLLYPPWDKNFTEN
DLLVRIGKHSRTRYERNIEKISMLEKIYIHPRYNWRENLDRDIALMKLKKPVAFSDYIHP
VCLPDRETAASLLQAGYKGRVTGWGNLKETWTANVGKGQPSVLQVVNLPIVERPVCKDST
RIRITDNMFCAGYKPDEGKRGDACEGDSGGPFVMKSPFNNRWYQMGIVSWGEGCDRDGKY
GFYTHVFRLKKWIQKVIDQFGE</fasta>
          </amino-acid-sequence>
          <gene-sequence>
            <fasta>&gt;1869 bp
ATGGCGCACGTCCGAGGCTTGCAGCTGCCTGGCTGCCTGGCCCTGGCTGCCCTGTGTAGC
CTTGTGCACAGCCAGCATGTGTTCCTGGCTCCTCAGCAAGCACGGTCGCTGCTCCAGCGG
GTCCGGCGAGCCAACACCTTCTTGGAGGAGGTGCGCAAGGGCAACCTAGAGCGAGAGTGC
GTGGAGGAGACGTGCAGCTACGAGGAGGCCTTCGAGGCTCTGGAGTCCTCCACGGCTACG
GATGTGTTCTGGGCCAAGTACACAGCTTGTGAGACAGCGAGGACGCCTCGAGATAAGCTT
GCTGCATGTCTGGAAGGTAACTGTGCTGAGGGTCTGGGTACGAACTACCGAGGGCATGTG
AACATCACCCGGTCAGGCATTGAGTGCCAGCTATGGAGGAGTCGCTACCCACATAAGCCT
GAAATCAACTCCACTACCCATCCTGGGGCCGACCTACAGGAGAATTTCTGCCGCAACCCC
GACAGCAGCACCACGGGACCCTGGTGCTACACTACAGACCCCACCGTGAGGAGGCAGGAA
TGCAGCATCCCTGTCTGTGGCCAGGATCAAGTCACTGTAGCGATGACTCCACGCTCCGAA
GGCTCCAGTGTGAATCTGTCACCTCCATTGGAGCAGTGTGTCCCTGATCGGGGGCAGCAG
TACCAGGGGCGCCTGGCGGTGACCACACATGGGCTCCCCTGCCTGGCCTGGGCCAGCGCA
CAGGCCAAGGCCCTGAGCAAGCACCAGGACTTCAACTCAGCTGTGCAGCTGGTGGAGAAC
TTCTGCCGCAACCCAGACGGGGATGAGGAGGGCGTGTGGTGCTATGTGGCCGGGAAGCCT
GGCGACTTTGGGTACTGCGACCTCAACTATTGTGAGGAGGCCGTGGAGGAGGAGACAGGA
GATGGGCTGGATGAGGACTCAGACAGGGCCATCGAAGGGCGTACCGCCACCAGTGAGTAC
CAGACTTTCTTCAATCCGAGGACCTTTGGCTCGGGAGAGGCAGACTGTGGGCTGCGACCT
CTGTTCGAGAAGAAGTCGCTGGAGGACAAAACCGAAAGAGAGCTCCTGGAATCCTACATC
GACGGGCGCATTGTGGAGGGCTCGGATGCAGAGATCGGCATGTCACCTTGGCAGGTGATG
CTTTTCCGGAAGAGTCCCCAGGAGCTGCTGTGTGGGGCCAGCCTCATCAGTGACCGCTGG
GTCCTCACCGCCGCCCACTGCCTCCTGTACCCGCCCTGGGACAAGAACTTCACCGAGAAT
GACCTTCTGGTGCGCATTGGCAAGCACTCCCGCACAAGGTACGAGCGAAACATTGAAAAG
ATATCCATGTTGGAAAAGATCTACATCCACCCCAGGTACAACTGGCGGGAGAACCTGGAC
CGGGACATTGCCCTGATGAAGCTGAAGAAGCCTGTTGCCTTCAGTGACTACATTCACCCT
GTGTGTCTGCCCGACAGGGAGACGGCAGCCAGCTTGCTCCAGGCTGGATACAAGGGGCGG
GTGACAGGCTGGGGCAACCTGAAGGAGACGTGGACAGCCAACGTTGGTAAGGGGCAGCCC
AGTGTCCTGCAGGTGGTGAACCTGCCCATTGTGGAGCGGCCGGTCTGCAAGGACTCCACC
CGGATCCGCATCACTGACAACATGTTCTGTGCTGGTTACAAGCCTGATGAAGGGAAACGA
GGGGATGCCTGTGAAGGTGACAGTGGGGGACCCTTTGTCATGAAGAGCCCCTTTAACAAC
CGCTGGTATCAAATGGGCATCGTCTCATGGGGTGAAGGCTGTGACCGGGATGGGAAATAT
GGCTTCTACACACATGTGTTCCGCCTGAAGAAGTGGATACAGAAGGTCATTGATCAGTTT
GGAGAGTAG</fasta>
          </gene-sequence>
          <pfams>
            <pfam>
              <identifier>PF00594</identifier>
              <name>Gla</name>
            </pfam>
            <pfam>
              <identifier>PF00051</identifier>
              <name>Kringle</name>
            </pfam>
            <pfam>
              <identifier>PF00089</identifier>
              <name>Trypsin</name>
            </pfam>
          </pfams>
          <go-classifiers>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>component</category>
              <description>extracellular region</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>binding</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>catalytic activity</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>thrombin activity</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>hydrolase activity</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>calcium ion binding</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>peptidase activity</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>ion binding</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>endopeptidase activity</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>cation binding</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>function</category>
              <description>serine-type endopeptidase activity</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>protein metabolism</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>proteolysis</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>cellular protein metabolism</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>organismal physiological process</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>regulation of body fluids</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>physiological process</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>hemostasis</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>blood coagulation</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>metabolism</description>
            </go-classifier>
            <go-classifier>
              <id/>
              <category>process</category>
              <description>macromolecule metabolism</description>
            </go-classifier>
          </go-classifiers>
        </polypeptide>
      </components>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <enzymes/>
  <carriers/>
  <transporters/>
```

Comment: what is the output you getting in console?

Comment: I get nothing or {} or null

Comment: I don't think calling on the contenthandler correctly?  Am I suppose to use handler?

Comment: Your code works allright .. I tried in debugger mode... Problem is with the logic .. Please recheck the logic ..

Comment: move `lookupCache.put(tempDrugModel.drugbankID, tempDrugModel);` to `if (localName.equals("drugbank-id")) {` of `startElement()` and try. but, debug your code and find some if conditions are prevents to add new `DrugModel`

Comment: I think my logic is definitely wrong. Going to start over. The first element of drug is not being put in. I'm getting null. First time doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried defining an XSD schema for the XML and using a JaxBContentHandler?

In my opinion is a much better implementation because:

- You can also retrieve the results from the POJO objects you have unmarshalled.
- If the XML format changes, you will only have to change the XSD schema and regenerate the POJO classes.

Only drawback I have seen is performance unmarshalling very big XML files.

Sample:

```
    // Create a JAXB context from the POJO classes (you should have defined the XSD before)
    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Drugs.class);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setSchema(null);
    // create a new XML parser
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XMLReader reader = factory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

    // JAXB marshaller
    reader.setContentHandler(unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler());

    // This is the buffer from you are reading (i.e. this can be the XML file)
    reader.parse(new InputSource(inputBuffer));

    Drugs result = (Drugs) marshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler().getResult();
    // Now you can build a hashmap with the drugs you have retrieved
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Maybe you can help me with this specific situation, I'm trying to parse Drugbank.ca, its huge.  Heres the site. http://www.drugbank.ca/downloads Its also has schema could that help?

Comment: You have the schema in the header of the XML: "http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd" You will need to generate the POJO classes (eclipse has a nice wizard to do that) from it. Then you can create the JAXBContext as shown above. The rest is very easy, you can reuse the code posted above (it does not require any 3pp apart from the JDK).

Comment: For creating the Java classes with Eclipse (is the way I usually do it): Go to new... JAXB Classes from Schema... Provide the XSD file and the target package and the JaxB compiler will generate the classes for you. Then just add those classes in your project and you are done.

Comment: This what I been doing today and I have stumble through and I have gotten some promising results. It seems to save me some time.  Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I have to extract this data and the plan is then connect it into visual graphs like jgrapht.  Thanks.